# Jquery ui tabs error

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I create tab with jquery ui and I want to tab appear after on click. But tabs title appear before on click in index page. How can I solve this problem?
(Hourly Forecast, 10 Day Forecast in shared image)

**CSS**

```
#tabs1{font-size: 14px;

}
.ui-widget-header {
    border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#here">Hourly Forecast</a></li>
    <li><a href="#here_table">10 Days Forecast</a></li>
  </ul>

   <div id="here"></div>
   <div id="here_table"></div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.noConflict();     
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs1").tabs();
});
```

Comment: Hi. Did you add jquery-ui css file?

Comment: You want to show tabs when user click some button?

Comment: Yes Tab is showed when user click. Before user click, I dont want to show Hourly Forecast and 10 Day Forecast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created working example for you.
You can hide tabs after page load like it:

```
var tabs = jQuery('#tabs1');
tabs.hide();
```

Then show after button clicked:

```
 jQuery('#someButtom').on('click', function() {
    tabs.show();
    jQuery("#tabs1").tabs();
});
```

working example on jsfiddle: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/92g42rju/3/)